# Особое форматирование текста в элементе

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Требуется по-особому отформатировать текст. Например, часть слов сделать одним шрифтом, часть - другим. Какой `Toolbox`, кроме `RichTextBox`, я могу использовать для этого?

Comment: WPF/WinForms? Если WinForms, то `RichTextBox` -- это единственный стандартный контрол, который поддерживает форматирование текста.

Comment: Можно компонент WebBrowser использовать. В нём обычный html.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На WPF можно задавать параметры шрифта в теге Run

```
<TextBlock>
    <Run FontSize="12">A</Run><Run FontSize="18">B</Run><Run FontSize="14">C</Run>
</TextBlock>
```

либо

```
<TextBlock>
    <Run FontSize="12" Text="A"/><Run FontSize="18" Text="B"/><Run FontSize="14" Text="C"/>
</TextBlock>
```

Answer (score 0):

Встроить MS Word в приложение как ActiveX компонент.